# How to save array of floats to database as one record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a array of 1,440 `float` values. What is the best datatype for saving this array in MySQL database? I heard about `blob`, is it good for this or not?

Comment: A table with an ID and one float per row is probably going to be best/most scalable depending on what you want to do with them.

Comment: These 1440 values is a measurements of some measaurands for one day. I have a 50 measurands for day. So, a I think, 50 records, which wil be contains a ID, measurands_type and blob of values for a one day is better anf faster then solutions where i have a one mesaruments as one row - its 72000 rows for one day.

Comment: So I would probably use text field and `json_encode()` the array.

Comment: Additionally, [MySQL allegedly supports JSON natively now](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html).

Comment: So, if I used a json_encode, which datatype in database is it? Can I use a longtext?